# Wikitude + Parse.com linker error

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm trying to add Parse to a project using Wikitude framework and I'm facing the "-ObjC" flag linker error.

I've found this error before with another library (GPUImage) and I managed to solve using "-force_load library" instead "-ObjC" but this time It seems this in not gonna work. When I add "-force_load path/to/Wikitude.framework" I get:

```
ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/Users/MyUser/Documents/MyProject/Frameworks/WikitudeSDK.framework' for architecture i386
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any other workaround for this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. It was easy. Just had to add the Facebook framework and everything went OK. I hope this helps someone.